# Mutually independent distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let the mutually independent random variables $X_1, X_2$, and $X_3$ be $N(0,1)$, $N(2,4)$, and $N(-1,1)$, respectively. Compute the probability that exactly two of these three variables are less than zero.

Comment: You can write math within \$ \$ to make your questions more readable :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $p_1$ be the probability $X_1$ is $\le 0$ (or $\lt 0$, same probability). Define $p_2$, $p_3$ analogously. The $p_i$ can be computed using properties of the normal. Of course, $p_1=1/2$. The other two are a bit more work.
Then our probability is
$$(1-p_1)p_2p_3+(1-p_2)p_1p_3+(1-p_3)p_1p_2.$$
The first term in our sum is the probability that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are less than $0$, but $X_1$ is not. The other terms have similar interpretations.